# Add source button to Magnolia CMS richText control

Tags: richtext, magnolia

I need to enable source button on my richText control ( I have to put there HTML code ) and I have follow this tutorial:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Rich+text

So I have added following settings source - true - Boolean in standard-templating-kit/dialogs/generic/controls/text  but it doesn't work for me.

I'm using Magnolia CMS 5.2.4. Can anybody please tell me how I can turn on this button or maybe if there is another control to put there html code ?

Best Regards
Jan

Comment: Works for me: I've downloaded 5.2.4 Magnolia Tomcat bundle, installed, and then added a `source` property to the [sktTextImage](http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.magnolia/admincentral#app:configuration:browser;/modules/standard-templating-kit/dialogs/components/content/stkTextImage/form/tabs/tabText/fields/text:treeview) dialog, set to `true`. Now I can edit the source of the Text field in the `Text and Image` component.

Comment: Hi Jozef. Thank you for the information. So perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I have created my own blossom component where I have used richText. After that I have set source property as mentioned before in standard-templating-kit/dialogs/generic/controls/text. So it seems that i'm doing it in wrong place. Changing stTextImage doesn't work for me as I'm not using this component I think.

Comment: I think that this is important to add in the context of configuration that I'm working with blossom and all components are written in spring mvc application, I have also my own template. When I run demo-features application, the source button is there. I can also find html component which are not accessible in my blossom application with my own template.

Comment: I've asket @sigget (author of the Blossom module) to add his two cents here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you defined your dialogs using Blossom? If so, they are completely distinct from the STK dialogs. If you have something like the following example, you will need to change your code to set up the rich text area with a source button.

```
@TabFactory("heading")
public void headingTab(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab) {

    FieldConfig fields = cfg.fields;

    tab.fields(
        fields.text("headingtitle").i18n().required(),
        fields.richText("headingtext").i18n().required()
    );
}
```

The above example would be modified by defining the rich text field and then modifying the definition.

```
@TabFactory("heading")
public void headingTab(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab) {

    FieldConfig fields = cfg.fields;

    RichTextFieldBuilder richText = fields.richText("headingtext").i18n().required();
    richText.definition().setSource(true);

    tab.fields(
        fields.text("headingtitle").i18n().required(),
        richText
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris J. It works for me. But I have one more question, whenever I'm putting there html code, switch to normal view and switch back to source view, the html code code is changed. This is very important for me to save the orginal html code as it is and to print it on the web page as html. Is it possible to force richText editor to not play with inserted text ?

Comment: Hi Johnny, glad to hear that helped. I'd recommend you open a new question for this issue in case someone else can help you quicker than I can.

Comment: Done :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289896/richtext-in-magnolia-cms-is-changing-html-text

Comment: Also, if my post answers your question, can you mark it as such please? Saves more people asking the same thing.