# RichText in Magnolia CMS is changing HTML text

Tags: richtext, magnolia

I would like to ask how I can block richText from changing html text under source view. 
I'm using Blossom module and defined richText as @Chris J advised me to do:
[Add source button to Magnolia CMS richText control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224875/add-source-button-to-magnolia-cms-richtext-control) 
Whenever I put html code in source code, switch to normal view and get back to source view the code is changed. For example the following part of code is missing :

```
<div class="components"> <div class="product col img-slider"> <div id="product-image" class="royalSlider productImage rsDefault"> <div class="rsContent"> <div class="rsTmb"><img src="/magnoliaPublic/resources/XXX/products/product_7.jpg" alt="">
```

and is replaced with folowing

```
<p><img alt="" src="/magnoliaPublic/resources/XXX/products/product_7.jpg" /></p>
```

I need to provide the possibility for the user to put html code and next to see in on the web page.

Regards
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan. I'd ask why you are using a rich text area if you are entering HTML. It is not really designed for this usage. Would you be better off with an ordinary text field? In the STK (you mentioned this in your previous question) you will find a component that serves exactly this purpose.

Under "Configuration" you will find it at **/modules/standard-templating-kit/templates/components/content/stkHTML**

You will see that the template script is simply:

```
[#if content.editHTML?has_content]
    ${cmsfn.decode(content).editHTML}
[/#if]
```

If you want to stick with a purely Blossom approach, you may need to recreate this but it is an incredibly simple component.

Incidentally, in Magnolia 5.4 there is a code editing field used in a similar component that offers syntax highlighting. You can see this by logging into the [demo site](https://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral) and trying to add an HTML component to the main area of the page [travel/contact](https://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:pages:detail;/travel/contact:edit).